# Make onclick row in table LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, wrapper-class, table

Hi guys ^^ I am new in programming and Salesforce.

I have little problem I wrote an apex class and now I want to make a custom tabele (that can't be a datatable) because in feature I will write a clickable row in this. Can you help me write a JS and html? I am new and I know the code can have a lot of mistakes please be lenient.
If u have another idea about write wire say it :D just I want to make a clickable row thats why i do it like it.

**APEX**

```
public with sharing class StockMarketSharesWrapper {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

    public static List<Wrapper> getAllCompanys(
        String Ticker,
        String Name
     ){
   
       

        // Define the list
        List<Wrapper> com = new List<Wrapper>(); 


        // Create account sObjects
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
        w.Ticker = 'U';
        w.Name = 'Unity Software Inc';
        Wrapper w1 = new Wrapper();
        w1.Ticker = 'UAL';
        w1.Name = 'United Airlines Holdings, Inc.' ;
        Wrapper w2 = new Wrapper();
        w2.Ticker ='DAOOU' ;
        w2.Name = 'Crypto 1 Acquisition Corp Unit';
        Wrapper w3 = new Wrapper();
        w3.Ticker = 'GLLIU';
        w3.Name ='Globalink Investment Inc. Unit' ;

        // Add accounts to the list
        com.add(w);
        com.add(w1);
        com.add(w2);
        com.add(w3);

        return com;
    }

    public class Wrapper{

@AuraEnabled
public String Name {get; set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String Ticker {get; set;}

} 

}
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from "lwc";
import getAllCompanys from "@salesforce/apex/StockMarketSharesWrapper.getAllCompanys";
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";

export default class FilteredTable extends NavigationMixin(
    LightningElement
) {

   

    Name = "";
    Ticker = "";

    


    @wire(getAllCompanys, { Ticker: '$Ticker', Name: '$Name'})
    fetchCompanies(data, error){
        alert('is in ????');
        if (error){
            this.Ticker= JSON.stringify(error);
            this.Name= JSON.stringify(error);
            return;
        }
        if(data.data){
            this.Ticker =data.data.Ticker;
            this.Name =data.data.Name
        }
       
    }
```

**HTML**

I know html is wrong but i saw a table like that in net and what do my table look like that.

```
<template>
    

    <lightning-card variant="Narrow">
        <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
            <lightning-layout-item
                size="12"
                padding="around-small"
            >
                <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
                    <thead>
                        
                    <!-- 
                        <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                            <th scope="col">Index</th>
                            
                            <th scope="col">Case Number</th>
                            <th scope="col">Account Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Contact</th>
                            
                            <th scope="col">Status</th>
                            <th scope="col">Priority</th>
                            <th scope="col">Subject</th>
                        </tr>--> 


                        
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr
                            class="slds-hint-parent"
                            for:each={searchable}
                            for:item="item"
                            key={item.Id}
                        >
                            <td scope="col">{item.index}</td>
                            <th scope="row">
                                <a
                                    href="#"
                                    onclick={handleNavigate}
                                    data-id={item.caseData.Id}
                                >{item.caseData.CaseNumber}
                                </a>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="row">
                                <span if:true={item.caseData.Account}>
                                    <a
                                        href="#"
                                        onclick={handleNavigate}
                                        data-id={item.caseData.Account.Id}
                                    >
                                        {item.caseData.Account.Name}
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="row">
                                <span if:true={item.caseData.Contact}>
                                    <a
                                        href="#"
                                        onclick={handleNavigate}
                                        data-id={item.caseData.Contact.Id}
                                    >
                                        {item.caseData.Contact.Name}
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="row">{item.caseData.Subject}</th>
                            <th scope="row">{item.caseData.Status}</th>
                            <th scope="row">{item.caseData.Priority}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**EDIT**

I know i can do wire like `@wire(getAllCompanys, {}) companys; but then I have no idea how to make onclick row table.`

**EDIT v2**
I just checked wire is response but when I am trying to pull it out to from HTML to UI it is not working. HTML cant see `{Ticker}, {Name}`

Answer (score 3):

Here you can use `data_table_custom_types` which Lighting data table provides. Just for opening records with `onClick` option no need of going full custom. We can extend Lighiting datatable and build an `onclick` functionality for records.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_custom_types

A working example is below. In this example I just queried some dummy records and showed how onClick of those relationship records you can open view page for those records.

[image]

Main Componennt:

```
<!-- Datatableexample -->
<template>
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <c-document-data-table
                key-field="Id"
                data={data}
                class="slds-customTable"
                ondatatablecolumnclickhandler={handleDatatableColumnClick}
                columns={columns}>
        </c-document-data-table>
    </div>
</template>

import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';
import getCasesWithAccount from '@salesforce/apex/DatatableExampleController.getCasesWithAccount';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

const columns = [
    {
        label: 'CaseNumber', type: 'datatableColumnClickHandler', typeAttributes: {
            recordId: {
                fieldName: 'Id'
            },
            cellValue: {
                fieldName: 'CaseNumber'
            },
            sObjectApiName: 'Case'
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Case Account', type: 'datatableColumnClickHandler', typeAttributes: {
            recordId: {
                fieldName: 'AccountId'
            },
            cellValue: {
                fieldName: 'AccountName'
            },
            sObjectApiName: 'Account'
        }
    }
];

export default class Datatableexample extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    data = [];
    columns = columns;

    // eslint-disable-next-line @lwc/lwc/no-async-await
    async connectedCallback() {
        this.data = await getCasesWithAccount();
        let preparedAssets = [];
        this.data.forEach(eachCase => {
            let preparedAsset = {};
            preparedAsset.Id = eachCase.Id;
            preparedAsset.CaseNumber = eachCase.CaseNumber;
            preparedAsset.AccountName = eachCase.Account.Name;
            preparedAsset.AccountId = eachCase.AccountId;
            preparedAssets.push(preparedAsset);
        });
        this.data = preparedAssets;
    }

    handleDatatableColumnClick(event) {
        let parsedDetail = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail));
        console.log(parsedDetail);
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: parsedDetail.recordId,
                objectApiName: parsedDetail.objectApiName,
                actionName: 'view'
            },
        });
    }
}
```

----- documentDataTable-----

```
<template>
    <c-datatable-column-click-handler s-object-api-name={typeAttributes.sObjectApiName}  record-id={typeAttributes.recordId} cell-value={typeAttributes.cellValue}></c-datatable-column-click-handler>
</template>
```

---

```
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import datatableColumnClickHandler from './datatableColumnClickHandler.html';
export default class CustomLightningDatatable extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes  = {
        datatableColumnClickHandler: {
            template: datatableColumnClickHandler,
            typeAttributes: ['recordId', 'cellValue', 'sObjectApiName']
        }
    }
}
```

------datatableColumnClickHandler ----

```
<template>
    <a class="slds-p-around_x-small" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick={handleClick}>
        {cellValue}
    </a>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class DatatableColumnClickHandler extends LightningElement {
    @api cellValue;
    @api recordId;
    @api sObjectApiName;

    handleClick() {
        const event = new CustomEvent('datatablecolumnclickhandler', {
            composed: true,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            detail: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                objectApiName: this.sObjectApiName,
            },
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

---

Apex class:

```
public without sharing class DatatableExampleController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Case> getCasesWithAccount(){
        return [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Id= '5007F00000P3gfBQAR'];
    }
}
```

Comment: `Note for OP`: the event should be fired with `bubbles: true` to be able to capture it from datatable component.